# Depend on the the values of the column I just query from the sqlite database's table, how could I show different icons on my HTML file?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the query command down below (in Python) that will later use to paginate and show all the blog on my website:

```
@core.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    form = Blogsearch_form(request.form)

    page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
    many_posts0 = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc())
    many_post = many_post0.paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('index.html', many_posts=many_posts, form=form)
```

My BlogPost table has a column named "problem_type" and there are some values in it like education, health... I wonder if there is any codes that could help me to show the education, health image icon based on the value in "problem_type" column.

The code below is wrong but I wanted to write some codes like:

```
if many_posts0(BlogPost.problem_type) == "education":
             icon_link = '../static/education.jpg'

if many_posts0(BlogPost.problem_type) == "health":
             icon_link = '../static/health.jpg'
```

Here is the important part of my HTML file:

```
<div class="container row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 text-center">
{% for post in many_posts.items%}

    <div class="card border-dark mb-3 " style="width: 20rem;">
     <div class="card-body ">
         <p class="text-primary text-left">#{{ post.problem_type }}</p>
         <h7><a class="text-warning" href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.creator.first_name+post.creator.middle_name+post.creator.last_name) }}"><img class="text-center rounded" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/'+ post.creator.profile_image) }}" width = "35" height = "35" alt=""> {{ post.creator.first_name}} {{ post.creator.middle_name }} {{ post.creator.last_name }}</a></h7>
         <p></p>
         <img class="text-center rounded responsive1" alt="" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='blog_pics/'+ post.blog_image) }}" width = "495" height = "250">
         {# Need caution for post.blog_image on the code above #}
         <p></p>
         <h2><a class="card-tittle text-body problem" href="{{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_view', blog_validated_id=post.blog_id) }}">{{ post.problem_name[0:40]}}..</a></h2>
         <p class="card-text">{{ post.text[0:100] }}</p>
         <p><small class="text-muted">Posted on: {{ post.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small></p>
         <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ url_for('blog_posts.blog_view', blog_validated_id=post.blog_id) }}">Read more</a>
     </div>


    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

As you see above, I could show the "problem_type" value of each post by using {{post.problem_type}} but I would like something like below to show the icon depends on its "problem_type" id:

```
{{post.problem_type}} <img src=”{{icon_link}}}” width = "30" height = "30" alt="">
```

I'm a beginner and I'm struggling with this problem. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me. Thank you!

P.s/By the way, I'm querying from a SQLite database using sqlalchemy. I'm also using Flask.

Comment: Like you have used the for loop with  templating language , you can use the if-else aswell. Example  - `{% if loop.index == 'X' %} `

Comment: Hi Sowjanya! Thank you for helping me! So in my example, I will use something like `{% if post.problem_type == 'X'%} enter down-> <img ....>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if post.problem_type == 'X' %}
     <img src={URL for problem_type 'X'}....>
{% elif post.problem_type == 'Y' %}
     <img src={URL for problem_type 'Y'}....>
{% else %}
     <img src={URL for general image}....>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is awesome!! So instead of using `<img src={URL for problem_type 'X'}....>, could I just use direct path to the image: <img src='..static/A/b'....> ?

Comment: yes you can use the <img> just like you use elsewhere - either use static src attribute or dynamic src - both will work fine. whole lot of examples here  => https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/   or   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/

Comment: It worked!! Thank you for helping me and thank you for sharing learning materials with me!!